# How to get the creation date of a docker volume

Tags: docker, date, inspect, volumes

How to get the creation date of a docker volume without using the docker gui for windows. With debian linux there is no gui for that.
In VS Code with docker extension there is also no way to see the creation date.

with inspect it is possible but if i have many volumes with cryptic names it is hard to determine which one was created last

is there a convienient way with linux terminal to list those date sorted?

i tried inspect ---> docker volume inspect

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `jq` command to extract the informaiton you want from `docker volume inspect`:

```
docker volume ls --format '{{ .Name }}' |
  xargs -n1 docker volume inspect |
  jq -r '.[0]|[.Name, .CreatedAt]|@tsv' |
  sort -k2
```

Which on my system produces something like:

```
exvpn_ssh_data  2022-10-30T22:40:34-04:00
exvpn_ssh_hostkeys      2022-10-30T23:04:21-04:00
exvpn_vpn_status        2022-10-31T23:18:20-04:00
postfix_mailboxes       2022-12-18T11:02:04-05:00
postfix_postgres_data   2022-12-18T11:02:04-05:00
postfix_greylist_data   2022-12-18T11:02:05-05:00
postfix_postfix_spool   2022-12-18T11:02:05-05:00
postfix_postfix_data    2022-12-18T11:02:07-05:00
postfix_postfix_config  2022-12-18T11:02:07-05:00
postfix_sockets 2022-12-18T19:46:59-05:00
```

Note that we're sorting things lexically, but because of the way the dates are written that ends up *also* being a chronological sort.

Comment: You can also run this in PowerShell: `docker volume ls --format '{{ .Name }}' | Foreach { docker volume inspect $_ | ConvertFrom-Json } | Foreach { $_ | Select-Object -Property Name, CreatedAt } | Sort-Object -Property CreatedAt`

Answer (score 1):

Listing all docker volumes and their creation date without any additional tools required.

1. Getting the list of all docker volumes `docker volume ls`
2. Passing that list to `docker volume inspect`
3. Sorting by ascending date

```bash
docker volume ls --quiet | xargs docker volume inspect --format '{{ .CreatedAt }} {{ .Name }}' | sort
```